# Add delays to the requests coming from a particular ip address

Tags: linux, networking, iptables, linux-networking

Is there any way to add delay to the requests coming from a particular server for testing purposes. I have tried checking tc command which adds delay for all the requests. I have also checked if there is any delay option in IPtables. In short, i need to intercept all the requests from a particular ip address, wait for a minute and then let it process the request(add latency to the requests)

Comment: The server runs on debian and any external packages cannot be downloaded

Comment: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.qdisc.filters.html has examples how to use IP addresses with `tc`.

Comment: http://info.iet.unipi.it/~luigi/dummynet/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use iptables to mark the packets

```
sudo iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -s <source_ip> -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Now use tc to shape the traffic

```
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: prio
sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:1 handle 10: netem delay 100ms
```